# update and delete with stored procedures in ormlite .net

Tags: c#, asp.net, ormlite-servicestack

trying to update using stored procedures in ormlite i currently have this but it doesn't seem to be working.

```
public void UpdateUsers(DATOS.Users users)
{
    _db.SqlScalar<DATOS.Users>("exec updateUsers set @Username, @password, @id_room, @id_rol", new { Username = users.Username, Password = users.password, Id_room = users.id_room, id_rol = users.id_rol });
}
```

also what will do the trick for the delete?

Comment: What isn't working? Are you getting an error message?

Comment: no, is just not doing anything

Comment: answer on duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/43405114/85785