# Delete and update with stored procedure in ormlite (SQL Server) & C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, ormlite-servicestack

Trying to update using stored procedures in ormlite. I currently have this but it doesn't seem to be working. No error displayed, just does nothing.

```
public void UpdateUsers(DATOS.Users users)
{
    _db.SqlScalar<DATOS.Users>("exec updateUsers set @Username, @password, @id_room, @id_rol", new { Username = users.Username, Password = users.password, Id_room = users.id_room, id_rol = users.id_rol });
}
```

Also what will do the trick for the delete?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the stored procedure doesn't return anything use [db.ExecuteSql()](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite#custom-insert-and-updates) instead, e.g:

```
db.ExecuteSql("exec updateUsers @Username, @password, @id_room, @id_rol", 
    new { Username = users.Username, 
          Password = users.password, 
          Id_room = users.id_room, 
          id_rol = users.id_rol });
```

Likewise with Delete's:

```
db.ExecuteSql("exec deleteUsers @Username, @password, @id_room, @id_rol", 
    new { Username = users.Username, 
          Password = users.password, 
          Id_room = users.id_room, 
          id_rol = users.id_rol });
```

Comment: i did try but there's an error now. On the ExecuteSql